# Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Update from LiveCdRecovery

Tags: 16.04, live-usb, data-recovery, live-cd

I am trying to update `Ubuntu 16.04 LTS` from `LiveCdRecoveryusing` (USB Stick) using the instructions given [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCdRecovery). The instructions are:

**Update Failure**

If there was an update that made your system non-bootable and they have fixed it in the repositories, you can use the Live CD to run apt-get to get the new files to fix your system.

1. Boot the Ubuntu Live CD.
2. Press Ctrl-Alt-F1
3. sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
4. sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev
5. sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc
6. sudo mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys
7. sudo chroot /mnt
8. apt update
9. apt upgrade

However, I am troubling with the above commands. First three work fine whereas fourth one throws error:

1. Boot the Ubuntu Live CD.
2. Press Ctrl-Alt-F1
3. sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
4. sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev

   mount: mount point /mnt/dev does not exist

I would highly appreciate if someone help me to figure out the problem. Thanks in advance.

**Edited**

The output of `sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda` is:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 298.1 GiB, 320072933376 bytes, 625142448 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x0008a792

Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *         2048    206847    204800   100M  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2          206848 102402047 102195200  48.7G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3       102402048 307202047 204800000  97.7G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda4       307204094 614682623 307478530 146.6G  f W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sda5       307204096 409604095 102400000  48.8G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda6       409606144 585385983 175779840  83.8G 83 Linux
/dev/sda7       585388032 614682623  29294592    14G 82 Linux swap / Solaris

Partition 4 does not start on physical sector boundary.
```

Comment: First use the fdisk utility to list the partitions on a device.  Type the following: 'sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda'

Comment: Thanks @kyodake for your comment and please see my edits.

Comment: @Mayseen208  try with "sudo mount /dev/sda6 /mnt"